# How to connect to older MYSQL server (4.1)

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have a very old MySQL server 4.1.

When i try to access it using the MYSQL workbench 5.2 i get the error message that this MYSQL Server is older than 5.0 and hence not supported.

How can i query this MYSQL server databases?

PS: Upgrading the MYSQL server 4.1 is not an option for me at the moment.
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You can open cmd in windows and cd to MySQL Server 4.1\bin
and type

*mysql -u root -p*

to use command line write query on the server. Workbench is not the only options to make query to the mysql server.

**More Information:**
In case you just have the database copy.
You can first download the mysql 4.1 server from 
http://mysql.localhost.net.ar/downloads/mysql/4.1.html
Run the setup until you see a file created MySQL Server 4.1 in the program file(x86) and a service named MySQL started
Stop the service
Then backup the data file of this server (change data to data-original)
and put the data file of your server to it.
You may need to copy back ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 of your backup file to this file.
If you don't know what is the user that have the privilege on using the server.
You can add the following lines under [mysqld]
skip-grant-tables